# const_iterator to iterator C++ Error

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, constants

I'm trying to iterator through a `map` object using the following chunk of code:

```
for(map<int, vector>::iterator table_iter = table.being(); table_iter != table.end(); table_iter++)
{
    ...
}
```

And I keep getting errors telling me:

> conversion from const_iterator to non-scalar type iterator requested

And I can't seem to determine why the iterator would be `const` vs. not-`const`, or how to deal with this.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: The line I posted; the `for` loop line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `map<int, vector>::const_iterator` instead which is returned by `map::begin`.

Comment: I've noticed that on occasion, using an iterator works without issue, and then others where I need to use a const_iterator. It seems to do with scoping, since I had this error come up while running a .begin() function call on a vector that had been captured by a lambda [=].
Any idea why this behaviour exists? Is there anywhere with more info on this topic? Thanks!

Comment: It can be that way if the container is `const`, or if the member function it is called from is `const` (`void class::memberfunction() const`)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `table` is a `const` object or reference, in which case `begin` returns a `const_iterator`. Change your for-loop to this:

```
// typedefs make for an easier live, note const_iterator
typedef map<int, vector>::const_iterator iter_type;
for(iter_type table_iter = table.begin(); table_iter != table.end(); table_iter++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or the iterator is defined within a `const` member function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question was partially answered.

"And I can't seem to determine why the iterator would be const vs. not-const, or how to deal with this."
As others answered, if your table is defined as a constant you need to define a const iterator.
What was missing is that if the function is defined as const the iterator should be const as well.

I figured a const function was your issue rather than a const table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing table is a const&.